# Set network shared folder only allowing admin users

Tags: c++, share

I'm trying to create a shared folder allowing only the admin users to write/read from it.

This is what I have:

```
 NET_API_STATUS res;
 SHARE_INFO_2 p;
 DWORD parm_err = 0;

      // Fill in the SHARE_INFO_2 structure.
      //

      p.shi2_netname = TEXT("QueuesSHAREDTest");    
      p.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE; // disk drive
      p.shi2_remark = TEXT("TESTSHARE to test Queues Folders");
      p.shi2_permissions = 0;    
      p.shi2_max_uses = -1;
      p.shi2_current_uses = 0;    
      p.shi2_path = TEXT(Path);
      p.shi2_passwd = NULL; // no password
      //
      // Call the NetShareAdd function,
      //  specifying level 2.
      //
      res=NetShareAdd(NULL, 2, (LPBYTE) &p, &parm_err);
      //
      // If the call succeeds, inform the user.
      //
      if(res==0)
         printf("Share created.\n");

      // Otherwise, print an error,
      //  and identify the parameter in error.
      //
      else
         printf("Error: %u\tparmerr=%u\n", res, parm_err);
```

I can't find the options for the sharing permisions.
This only allows me to set write/read/execute... permissions.

Any one did this before and can help a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control who can access a share by setting the DACL (Discretionary Access Control List) on the share.

You can do that by calling [`GetNamedSecurityInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645.aspx) to retrieve the current permissions on the object, then modify the DACL, then call [`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579.aspx) to associate the modified DACL with the share.

Alternatively, you could call [`NetShareGetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525388.aspx) with [information level 503](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc462916.aspx) to retrieve the current security descriptor, then modify the DACL, and then call [`NetShareSetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525389.aspx) with [information level 1501](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525406.aspx) to associate the modified security descriptor with the share.

Lacking a really good reason to do otherwise, however, I'd use Get/SetNamedSecurityInfo. Manipulating DACLs is painful enough -- you don't need to add any extra difficulty.